# "expected ')' before textIn" and "expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before '(' token"

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

I've looked through multiple threads, but they are either completely different problems or people not knowing how to create constructors. I get the titles first error in my header, and the second error in the cpp file itself.

MenuItem.h

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <string>

#ifndef MENUITEM_H
#define MENUITEM_H

class MenuItem
{
            public:
                //Below constructor creates the first error
                MenuItem(string textIn="", float x, float y, bool highlightedDefault=false);
                bool highlighted;
                sf::Text text;
};

#endif // MENUITEM_H
```

MenuItem.cpp

```
#include "MenuItem.h"

MenuItem::MenuItem(string textIn, float x, float y, bool highlightedDefault)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: strings are in the std namespace. Also, only the last function parameters can be defaulted. It looks like you need a good C++ textbook.

Comment: Perhaps I do need a book, since I had no clue about the default parameter requirement. Me not having std:: before string is just a derp on my part, too used to most other languages were you don't need it.

Comment: @Alfie I don't understand what you are asking -  as it stands the function won't compile and so cannot be called.

Comment: @ThatMartinGuy - consider a function that has 4 int parameters, but the first and last have defaults.  You pass 3 arguments to it.  Which default should it use?  This is why the requirement exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Neil Butterworth stated that you need `std::string textin` also you need to change the position of your parameters. Like this:

```
class MenuItem
{
            public:
                //Below constructor creates the first error
                MenuItem(float x, float y,std::string textIn="", bool highlightedDefault=false);
                bool highlighted;
               sf::Text text;
};
MenuItem::MenuItem(float x, float y, std::string textIn, bool highlightedDefault)
{
    ....
}
```

default values go from right to left.